# Flexbox child does not have declared padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I just can figure out why the right button has not enough padding.

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<div class="col-span-2 flex gap-0.5 items-center justify-between">
   <p>Wie möchten Sie ihre Antwort erhalten?</p>
   <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1.5">
      <div
         class="whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-black px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none text-white"
         >
         E-Mail
      </div>
      <div
         class="whitespace-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none"
         >
         Telefon
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, or do you mean the parent container?

Comment: your current code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/WDPogcXGfL works fine, it might be from a certain parent container

Comment: I don't know these tailwind classes, but from the image and the code it looks like the buttons either have a fixed width or are shortened by the flex/grid settings. A padding obviously exists on both buttons, but the text in the right one overflows the right padding due to the too small overall width.

Comment: @NishantJadhav when you add `max-w-md w-full` to the parent div you can see my problem.

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/3d7HGwwuyn

Comment: @Ruudy if you change 'max-w-md' to 'max-w-lg' it will have more space so all elements will fit, resulting in your expected behaviour for button's padding.

Comment: Sure, but I want so work it without a fixed max width. Should be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: none` to the buttons so they don't shrinking:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="col-span-2 flex gap-0.5 items-center justify-between">
   <p>Wie möchten Sie ihre Antwort erhalten?</p>
   <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1.5 flex-none">
      <div
         class="whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-black px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none text-white"
         >
         E-Mail
      </div>
      <div
         class="whitespace-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none"
         >
         Telefon
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1` to the `<p>` element. This means that the grid container for the buttons will be "prioritized" in its width. This allows its buttons to be their natural width.  Any remaining parent horizontal space is then filled by the `<p>` element:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="w-full flex gap-0.5 items-center justify-between p-10">
  <p class="basis-0 grow">Wie möchten Sie ihre Antwort erhalten?</p>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1.5">
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-black px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none text-white">
      E-Mail
    </div>
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none">
      Telefon
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="max-w-md w-full flex gap-0.5 items-center justify-between p-10">
  <p class="basis-0 grow">Wie möchten Sie ihre Antwort erhalten?</p>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1.5">
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-black px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none text-white">
      E-Mail
    </div>
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-3 text-center leading-none">
      Telefon
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```